# Angular animate background of selected item in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have some code that looks roughly like this.  It's a list of items, and one of them is selected.

```
 <div ng-repeat='item in items'
      ng-click='selectItem(item)'
      ng-class="{ selected: selectedItem == item }"
      class="selected-item-animation">
   ...
 </div>
```

I have CSS for the `selected` class (background-color) and added a CSS transition, thinking I could fade a background color in and out, as items are selected. But it doesn't work in Angular, and I think it's because every time there is a event that changes the selected item, it recreates these divs for the list.  So as far as CSS is concerned, it's not a transition.

So I tried a [JS animation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)...

```
.animation('.selected-item-animation', function($log) {  
  return {
    enter: function(element, done) {
      $log.log("enter", element.hasClass('selected'));
      done();
      return function(cancelled) {    };
    },
    leave: function(element, done) {
      $log.log('leave');
      done();
    },

    addClass: function(element, className, done) {
      $log.log("Added class! " + className);
    },     
  };
```

But the only thing that gets triggered in the `enter`. The others are never called.  So how am I supposed to animate away the selected background color if I'm never notified of the un-selection?

Comment: Angular only triggers the enter and leave events when something is added and removed from the list. You could hack this by removeing and then adding something to the list when it is selected. e.g. http://plnkr.co/edit/AaQhjcMcLETwvWKw66le?p=preview